# Sitecore 9.1 distributed architecture - how to create two processing node through PS script

Tags: powershell, sitecore-install-assistant

Sitecore 9.1 initial release .

Is there a way to create two processing nodes with PowerShell script or should it be done manually. If it needs to be done manually, what all settings to be taken care of ?

Can you any share the details?

Comment: Why do you need two separate processing servers?

Comment: Based on the client requirement, the architecture is suggested